# Javascript not loading on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

First of all, this is my JS

```
function getTimeRemaining(endTimeInput) {
var endTime = new Date(endTimeInput);
var currentTime = new Date();

var t = endTime - currentTime;

var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

return {
 total: t,
 days: days,
 hours: hours,
 minutes: minutes,
 seconds: seconds,
 }
}

var dejts = [
{
    number: 1,
    date: Date.parse("2015-12-07 21:13"),
    text: "text1"
},
{
    number: 2,
    date: Date.parse("2015-12-31 06:00"),
    text: "text2"
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){
  init();
});


function init(){
var eighteenHours = 18*1000*60*60;

    for (i=0 ; i<dejts.length ; i++){
        var currentDejt = dejts[i];
        var now = new Date();

        if (currentDejt.date + eighteenHours - now > 0){
            startTimer(currentDejt);
            break;
        }
    }

}




function startTimer(dejt){

 var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var t = getTimeRemaining(dejt.date);
  $('#date-counter').text(dejt.number.toString());
 // document.getElementById('date-counter').innerHTML = dejt.number;
  document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = t.days + ' d';
  document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = t.hours + ' h';
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = t.minutes + ' m';
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = t.seconds + ' s';

  if (t.total < 0){
      clearInterval(interval);
      document.getElementById('date-counter').innerHTML = dejt.number;
      document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = '0 d';
      document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = '0 h';
      document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = '0 m';
      document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = '0 s';

      displayDejtText(dejt);

  }


}, 1000);
}


function displayDejtText(dejt){

$('.heart-content').html("<p>" + dejt.text + "</p>");

}
```

When accessing my page from my laptop using chrome or safari it works great but when I try to access it from my iPhone 5S (chrome and safari), the Javascript is not loading. I have tried to set console logs in document.ready and even above all code but nothing get logged when accessing it from mobile. I have remote debugged it using http://jsconsole.com/ but no errors/exceptions are logged. What am I doing wrong? The script is loaded in the html `<head>` tag together with jquery. I have tried to load it in the `<body>` but it makes no difference.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate the issue.I am not sure if your testing in real device or emulated mode,infact i tried to replicate in emulated mode.
Also I just added `type = 'text/javascript'` in script tag.

Here are the snapshot for reference.

[image: Snapshot 1]

[image: Snapshot 2]

Also you can try jquery mobile.